# Software to calculate Alexander polynomials

Tags: math-software, knot-theory

Is there any software for Windows that I can use to calculate the Alexander polynomials of links?

Answer (score 3):

SnapPy has a fairly simple to use link editor, and it can do twisted Alexander polynomials, so should be able to do vanilla ones. The relevant link is [here](http://www.math.uic.edu/t3m/SnapPy/snap.html?highlight=alexander).

Answer (score 1):

The Liverpool knot group has a nice [collection of knot theory software](http://www.liv.ac.uk/~su14/knotprogs.html) which all (as far as I know) take as input a braid decomposition of a knot, and output various invariants of the closed braid depending on which program you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I like [this](http://www.artsci.kyushu-u.ac.jp/~sumi/C/knot/), which seems to go by just the name 'Knot'. Although the input is essentially the same as for SnapPy (drawing the link), I've personally found it much easier to use.